# Html form into a Php table

Tags: php, html, css

So, im trying to get the informatino you put into an HTML into a Table in Php, problem is, i cant find any solutions online. and i dont know much about php yet. this is only my second time asking something so i still dont quite know the way you are supposed to fill in a question. anyway, here is the code in question:

HTML

```
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run~jkorpela/echo.cgi"method="post">
<div>
<label for="vnaam">Voornaam</label>
<input type="text" id="vnaam" name="vnaam" required/>
</div>
<div>
<label for="anaam">Achternaam</label>
<input type="text" id="anaam" name="anaam" required/>
</div>
<div>
<label for="tnum">Telefoon Nummer</label>
<input type="text" id="tnum" name="tnum" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="tnum">E-mail</label>
<input type="email" id="tnum" name="tnum" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="adres">Adres</label>
<input type="" id="adres" name="adres" required/> 
</div>
<div>

<label for="land">Land</label>
<select id="land" name="land">
    <option value="ned">Nederland</option>
    <option value="usa">Amerika</option>
    <option value="eng">Engeland</option>
    <option value="bel">België</option>
    <option value="fr">Frankrijk</option>
    <option value="ger">Duitsland</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="button">
 <button type="submit">Opsturen</button>

</div>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
 <style type="text/css">
 form {
 /* Just to center the form on the page */
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 400px;
 /* To see the outline of the form */
 padding: 1em;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 border-radius: 1em;
}
form div + div {
margin-top: 1em;
}
label {
   /* To make sure that all labels have the same size and are properly     aligned */
    display: inline-block;
width: 90px;
text-align: right;
}
 input, textarea {
/* To make sure that all text fields have the same font settings
   By default, textareas have a monospace font */
font: 1em sans-serif;

/* To give the same size to all text field */
width: 300px;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;

/* To harmonize the look & feel of text field border */
border: 1px solid #999;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
/* To give a little highlight on active elements */
border-color: #000;
}
textarea {
/* To properly align multiline text fields with their labels */
vertical-align: top;

/* To give enough room to type some text */
height: 5em;

/* To allow users to resize any textarea vertically
   It does not work on all browsers */
resize: vertical;
}
.button {
/* To position the buttons to the same position of the text fields */
padding-left: 90px; /* same size as the label elements */
}
button {
/* This extra margin represent roughly the same space as the space
   between the labels and their text fields */
margin-left: .5em;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Since you're just starting to learn PHP, do it right - AVOID the `mysql_` extension entirely! You can use `mysqli_` (note the `i` at the end) or PDO instead. Be sure to use prepared statements with placeholders to protect your database. Check out the doucmentation for examples: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php or if you want to try PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php -- also CSS is irrelevant to this question, as CSS has to do with the look/styling of your page, while PHP is a backend language and simply don't care what it looks like ;-)

Comment: read about php form handling 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there about handling forms with PHP. Read through a few and take the time to really understand then. Then make an attempt yourself. After that, if you're still having trouble, post the PHP code you're using, describe the desired behavior, and describe the actual behavior, including any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <form method='POST' action='formhandler.php'>
    <input type='text' name='name' value='john'>
    <input type='text' name='address' value='32 flowers street'>
    <input type='text' name='email' value='john@example.com'>
 </form>
```

A typical form like this one will be delivered to the php file `formhandler.php` by the browser.

Then you handle it in your `formhandler.php` file

**formhandler.php**

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$address= isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : "";
$email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
echo $name; //john
echo $address; //32 flowers street
echo $email; //john@example.com
```

Now you have the form data. use it as you like, store them in a database, build another html response file to the user or do what ever you want to do with them.

for example, we are going to feedback the data to the user.

```
echo "We have successfully received your inputs as <br>
<table>
    <tbody>
       <tr><td>name</td><td>$name</td></tr>
       <tr><td>address</td><td>$address</td></tr>
       <tr><td>email</td><td>$email</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>";
```

**Note: in a real life production you need to [validate](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp) any inputs come to your php files first.**

Answer (score 0):

First change 
`<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run~jkorpela/echo.cgi"method="post">`

to Something like

```
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/getdata.php" method="post">
```

Because you are using `cgi-bin/run~jkorpela/echo.cgi` which is not used for get php data because its a `cgi` file. it should a `.php` extension file and `php` should be installed on your server. and I am assuming that `http://www.cs.tut.fi/` is the url for your website.

Where `getdata.php` is the php file where you get all your input values. You need to create that file on your server. If you are on `AWS` then it might be something like `/var/www/html/`

getdata.php

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```